# Switch Facebook Tabs inside iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml, fbjs, xfbml

How to you link from inside an iframe to another tab? When i normally link from inside the iframe it provides you with a

Do you have to use javascript ? if so how would you do that?

Example (the second carousel image):
http://www.facebook.com/pages/New-York-Life-DFW/116752861740593?sk=app_208195102528120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `target="_top"` just in case Facebook (or you) decided to wrap the whole thing inside another frame.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the that you can do it by setting the *target* of the link to "_parent"

i.e. this would be the link inside your iframe:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/some-other-tab" target="_parent">Go to another tab</a>
```